# How to calculate product of lags for an arbitrary number of lags in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is probably a very elementary problem, but I don't seem to get it working right. I need to calculate simple product of an element and certain number of its lags in R data.frame of time series data. I am trying to achieve this in `dplyr` pipe. E.g.:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(YEAR = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),
                 x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

dfFinal <- df %>% mutate(prodLag1 = prod(x, lag(x, 1), na.rm = T),
                         prodLag2 = prod(x, lag(x, 1), lag(x, 2), na.rm = T),
                         prodLag3 = prod(x, lag(x, 1), lag(x, 2), lag(x, 3), na.rm = T))
```

The result is not what I thought. E.g. with prodLag1 the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
dfFinal <- data.frame(YEAR = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),
                      x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                      prodLag1 = c(NA, 2, 6, 12, 20))
```

Additionally, I am aiming at lag = 10 and I would like to find more feasible way than just typing each individual lag in. Would `Reduce` work for this?

Comment: `df %>% mutate(x*lag(x))` ?

Comment: `prod` multiplies all the elements of the vector `x`, so `prodLag1` is `x` and `lag(x)` all multiplied together, i.e. 1*2*3*4*5*1*2*3*4=2880.  Just use `*` to multiply vectors element-by-element.

Comment: Thanks! Of course. I still need think how to do that serialization.

Comment: `cumprod` might be useful - then `prodLagN` would be `cumprod(x)/lag(cumprod(x),N+1)`.  If it is a big dataframe, it might be better to use `cumsum(log(x))`, and `prodLagN = exp(cumsum(log(x))-lag(cumsum(log(x)),N+1))` or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing prodLag10...

```
dfFinal <- df %>% mutate(cumlog = cumsum(log(x)),
                         prodLag10 = exp(cumlog-lag(cumlog,11)))
```